# Core Data Exporting all tables

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an app that creates individual events and stores them in core data. What I need to do it load one individually and then export it by email. The code below works except it exports every event where I need it to just export the index path selected one. The code does load the appropriate record because the NSLog (@"My record is: %@", currentItem); does display only the settings for that event but when the data is exported to email all events are sent. I need the selected event with the event name to export. Any thoughts?

```
NSInteger index = exportevent.tag;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];


CDBaseItem *rawRecord = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CDSurveyItem *surveyItem = [CDSurveyItem castObject:rawRecord];

self.recordEditID = [rawRecord.objectID URIRepresentation];
NSManagedObjectID *objectId = [self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:self.recordEditID];
TSPItem *currentItem = [self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:objectId];

NSString *eventName = nil;
if (currentItem.eventname) {
    eventName = currentItem.eventname;


}
else if (surveyItem.eventname) {
    eventName = surveyItem.eventname;
}


[self setSelection:indexPath];


if (self.selection)
{



    if (currentItem)
    {
        NSLog (@"My record is: %@", currentItem);

   NSData *export = [CDJSONExporter exportContext:currentItem.managedObjectContext auxiliaryInfo:nil];

        MFMailComposeViewController *composeVC1 = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

        composeVC1 = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        composeVC1.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [composeVC1 setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Settings From %@ Event", eventName]];

        [composeVC1 setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Here is the event settings. Simply press on the attachment and then choose Open in iPIX"] isHTML:NO];

        [composeVC1 addAttachmentData:export mimeType:@"application/octet-stream" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.ipix", eventName]];
        [self presentViewController:composeVC1 animated:NO completion:^(void){}];

    }

    [self setSelection:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `NSLog` may be correct, but you're not exporting the thing that you're printing. In this line (which I assume is a reference to [this project](https://github.com/mruegenberg/CDJSONExporter)):

```
NSData *export = [CDJSONExporter exportContext:currentItem.managedObjectContext auxiliaryInfo:nil];
```

You're telling `CDJSONExporter` to export the **context**, not a single object. You get every object because *that is what `CDJSONExporter` does*. It gets everything it can find in the context and gives you a data object. It's not designed to do what you're asking it to do.

If you want to convert a single object to JSON, you could

- Roll your own JSON conversion code. Since you know what the object looks like, this would be easy. Or...
- Implement `Encodable` on your model object and then use `JSONEncoder` to convert to JSON. Or...
- Find some other open source project that does what you want, instead of this one which does not.